Is it possible to use an external monitor with a laptop without the dedicated GPU?
I bought a new monitor to use with my laptop and I noticed that it is using the Nvidia GPU in my laptop.
I'm using the Acer Nitro AN515-57 along with the HP Omen 24.
If I'm not mistaken, I'm pretty sure previously my games and other applications used to run on the Nvidia GPU but the laptop monitor itself used the Intel GPU.
Is it possible to do this for the external monitor that I connected with a HDMI cable?
i.e. all the graphics using the discreet Nvidia GPU but the monitor only using the Intel GPU?
Edit 2: Not asking about application specific 3d settings in nvidia control panel.
There are other settings in nvidia control panel that shows which display is using which processor. This is further confirmed by checking looking at the activities of the intel and nvidia gpu in task manager and also in OMEN gaming hub and nitrosense.

Without the laptop model, this can't be answered since it depends on the laptop and how the OEM routed the HDMI port and/or DisplayPort - some are allowed to route through both the integrated and discrete GPUs, whereas others are restricted to one or the other. For example, on my Alienware, the HDMI port is routed through the discrete GPU, whereas the DisplayPort is routed through the integrated GPU.

@JW0914 Yeah, this is what I was afraid of. I thought my laptop had a displayport but it only has the HDMI and a usb c port. And I can't find any option to change the display adapter for the monitor.

If the USB-C supports connecting a monitor them most likely it supports Displayport-Alt mode. A simply adapter USB-C to Displayport should make it usable if your monitor has a Displayport in but not USB-C.

@Robert I was considering that as well. But I need to find out more about whether that will be practical for me.
I'm mostly concerned about colour accuracy and fps since I'll be mainly using the monitor for some graphics work and some gaming sometimes.

fps? I think latency would be more important as the fps is not changed by passive adapters which only "extract" the Displayport signals from USB-C and forward it in a pure Displayport cable. Only if the adapter is an USB based graphic card than 3D capabilities and thus fps would be different.

@Robert I've actually used the usb c port on my laptop to play pcvr games before. So, the usb c to displayport adapter idea seems even more plausible now.
But I need to be sure that It'd work.

There is nothing inherent to the integrated or discrete GPU that determines whether or not you can connect an external display. This is, essentially, entirely up to the manufacturer and their own choices. I have run many laptops with integrated and with dedicated GPUs and all have supported external displays, all have had external graphics ports of various sorts, and the modern ones have supported various forms of DisplayPort or HDMI over USB-C as well.

@music2myear well, yeah. But my question was more about choosing the integrated gpu for the display instead of the discreet gpu. As was the case for my laptop screen. But I cannot find the option to do that for my external monitor.
Basically, I'm trying to reduce the load on my discreet gpu.
I'm already using HDMI but have ordered a usb c to displayport cable for a better experience.
Will edit the OP to share my experiences.

When you say you want to reduce load on your discrete (that's how you spell this word, not "discreet" as you've been using) GPU, why? Is there any evidence that the load on the discrete GPU is causing problems? This still feels like a question in search of a problem, and the title also does not match what your comments have indicated. Please take some time to clarify the issue here for us: The REASON this is a problem, clarity and consistence in what you're looking for across both the title and the question body, etc.

@music2myear I was simply inquiring about whether it's possible or not.
My problem is overheating. I want to keep the temps in my laptop as low as possible. And when the rtx gpu along with the intel cpu is working at nearly their full capacity, temps can usually go higher than I'm comfortable with.
Frankly, I don't understand on what grounds the OP was closed.
The question was very clear and I edited in more details when needed. But I digress.

Windows allows you to associate specific applications to specific GPUs. I am not aware of a way to tell Windows to associate an entire display to a specific GPU.
It has never been the case that the laptop's internal display used the internal graphics only, but always that individual applications were assigned to the different devices based on workload.
In case your system is actually behaving in a non-optimal way, assigning workloads incorrectly and inefficiently, the way to resolve this is going to be to make sure your OS, applications, drivers, and firmware are all updated to the latest stable or available versions.
If you've already completed these updates, you can manually assign applications to specific GPUs. To tell a specific application to use a particular GPU:

Open Settings > Display
Scroll to the bottom, under Related Settings, and click Graphics
If the app you want is not yet listed, under Add an app choose Desktop App or Microsoft Store App, and click Browse
Choose the application you wish to apply the setting to
Once the program is listed, select it and click Options
Select the GPU or power setting you wish to associate with this application and click Save


Practically it will associate the display with the GPU its running on unless there's another setting like that overriding it.

I know about directly assigning gpus to applications with the nvidia control panel.
But when I'm using just my laptop without the external monitor, it shows up under the PhysX configuration settings where the laptop display is shown as linked to the Intel(R) UHD Graphics.
When I connect my external monitor via hdmi there are more options under the video settings and others where it clearly shows that the discreet gpu is being used by the monitor.
